# When do you implement the Sigmoid function in a neural network?

Tags: java, neural-network, sigmoid

I am getting into some neural networks because it seemed fun. I translated the python code to java and it works like it should I think. It gives me the correct values every time. Although I want to know where do you implement the Sigmoid function in the code. I implemented it after I calculated the output, but even without the Sigmoid function it works the same way.

Website I learned from: https://towardsdatascience.com/first-neural-network-for-beginners-explained-with-code-4cfd37e06eaf

```
This is my Perceptron function:
    public void Perceptron(int input1,int input2,int output) {
           double outputP = input1*weights[0]+input2*weights[1]+bias*weights[2];
           outputP = Math.floor((1/(1+Math.exp(-outputP))));
           if(outputP > 0 ) {
               outputP = 1;
           }else {
               outputP = 0;
           }
           double error = output - outputP;
           weights[0] += error * input1 * learningRate;
           weights[1] += error * input2 * learningRate;
           weights[2] += error * bias * learningRate;
           System.out.println("Output:" + outputP);
    }
```

Also if I don't add the Math.floor() it just gives me a lot of decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but it is used instead of your conditional where you output 1 or 0. That's your threshold function. In that case, you are using a **step function**; you could replace the whole conditional with your sigmoid function.